# Using a class instance with Wire.onReceive

Tags: wire-library

Is it possible to register a class instance member function with Arduino's [Wire.OnReceive](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireOnReceive)?

I'm trying to make my code object-oriented, and want a specific non-static class function to handle I2C data, but if I'm reading [this thread](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=116685.0) correctly, `onReceive` is incompatible with classes since it only accepts a function pointer, which won't store context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-static class member function has an implicit `ClassName *this` parameter inserted as the first parameter in the parameter list.

Because the function prototype required for `Wire.onReceive()` does not have that parameter specified in its parameter list a non-static member function is not compatible with it.

The same goes for `attachInterrupt()` and anything else that takes a function pointer.